# Alternate formulation of Calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Calculus is almost always made rigorous by one of two approaches: Riemann-Sums or Infinitesimals.  Students seem to have a lot of trouble with Riemann Sums.  So the following approach occurred to me that may be more accessible.  I was wondering if anybody has seen calculus done in the following way.

First for an interval $I=[a,b]\subseteq\Bbb R$, define $\text{PC}(I)$ to be the set of piecewise constant functions.  Then define $\int_I f$ for $f\in\text{PC}(I)$.  It's obviously very intuitive and natural to define the integral of something in $\text{PC}(I)$ since it's just a sum of rectangles.

For $f$ an arbitrary function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\Bbb R$ and $g\in\text{PC}(I)$ say $g\leq f$ if $g(x)\leq f(x)$ $\forall$ $x\in I$ and $g\geq f$ if $g(x)\geq f(x)$ $\forall$ $x\in I$.

Let $L(f)=\{g\in\text{PC}(I)\mid g\leq f\}$ and $U(f)=\{g\in\text{PC}(I)\mid g\geq f\}$. Define $$LI(f)\equiv\sup_{g\in L(f)}\int_Ig$$ and $$UI(f)\equiv\inf_{g\in U(f)}\int_Ig.$$

Then define $f$ is integrable iff $LI(f)=UI(f)$.

This avoids the whole business of partitions and the limits over partitions.  The only real painful thing the student has to go through is to understand sup and inf, which they would have to do anyway.

It seems to me many things would be easier to prove this way as well, like for example change of variables.

So I'm just wondering if anybody has developed all of calculus using this kind of approach.  Any feedback would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Some at my university do that. You just exchange struggle with partitions with struggle with step functions. Both concepts are "new" to students. I like the approach, as it is similar to Lebesgue integration.

Comment: @user251257 Thank you, would you happen to have access to any of your colleagues notes using this approach?  I agree there's no way to avoid all struggle, but it does seem more intuitive to go through step functions first than straight to partitions.

Comment: Unfortunately it is handwritten, in German, and not for public.

Comment: Why not just focus on partitions that have intervals of the same length?

Comment: @Taylor It's not a bad idea, but somehow the whole concept of partitions and Riemann sums puts a lot of students into a catatonic state.  It's obviously purely psychological, because the concept is simple.  But they are afraid because it's a more cumbersome type of mathematical object than they have seen before and deep inside they are paralyzed by fear.  Math concepts are always simple once you manage to understand them.  It's just the way we have to communicate math that makes it seem a lot harder than it really is.

Comment: @Taylor There are things that would be at least more awkward if we only allowed partitions of constant length. For example, showing that $\int_a^b+\int_b^c=\int_a^c.$

Comment: many thanks for your appreciation of my answer. The next time I will not waste time.

Comment: @Karl You didn't answer my question, so I'm not sure what you expect.  It would have been more appropriate as a comment.  You're just lucky nobody voted your answer down.  What a baby.

Comment: No need to become insulting. But If you need this, feel free to go on.

Comment: In the discussion, it can be useful to start from [D.Maxwell's exposition](http://www.dms.uaf.edu/~maxwell/AY2011/math641/RiemannIntegral.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

This also strikes me as very much like the Darboux integral.

You still have to do some work. In particular, seems like you need to show that $LI(f)\le UI(f)$. That's obvious, yes. How do you prove it?

Ok, it's obvious because if $g,h$ are piecewise constant and $g\le h$ then $\int_a^b g\le \int_a^b h$. Which is obvious. How do you prove it?

Oh. You just note that $h-g\ge0$ so $\int_a^b(h-g)\ge0$. Yes, it's obvious that the integral of something non-negative is non-negative. OOPS, we also need to know that $\int(h-g)=\int h-\int g$. That's obvious. How do you prove it?

Each one of those statements is easy from obvious things about refinements of partitions, plus the fact that any two partitions have a common refinement. But I don't see how to prove any of them without these notions (explicit or implicit). And then things are all complicated again...

Answer (score 0):

Lomg time ago when teaching maths to economists, I saw the same problem with Riemann sums.
I used this approach:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral

similar to yours.

Comment: Thank you that's a worthwhile answer.  But Darboux integral are still more like Riemann sums, there's a lot of talk of partitions and such.  Perhaps if I tried to flesh out the approach I'm asking about I'll be forced to go into nitty gritty of partitions too, but in any case it still seems more natural to do it by first defining integrals just on piecewise constant functions and then building up from there.  Just seems like it would be more palatable to the student.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: How do you define piecewise constant functions without defining partitions?

Comment: @GregoryGrant, I fear celtschk is right, me too I see no way to avoid partitions in such an approach, but one doesn't have to use these Riemann sum limits which made Darboux integrals simpler IMHO.

Comment: @celtschk Of course at some level we are all talking about the same thing.  But introducing the concept of a piecewise constant function just seems more down-to-earth and natural than the whole business of partitions and Riemann sums.  It's building up by first integrating constant functions, then piecewise constant, then integrable functions.  No need to talk about the norm of a partition.  I realize this is not a revolutionary difference, just slightly more intuitive.  Maybe if I get a minute I'll try to flesh it out to a full treatment.